# Need help refining a role approach

Tags: united-states, education, team-role, internal-transfer

I had an informational interview for a position, in which it was determined I was not a great fit, but we identified two other roles where I would potentially be a good match. One of the roles would be fine working from a remote office, however the other has a concern as it would be equivalent to the process owner, with some programming involved on an as needed basis.

The issues that were presented were getting up to speed on the process/product (SME), especially considering that everyone involved is extremely busy, and getting access is dicey when onsite, much less remote.

The approach that I briefly outlined was as follows:

- Identify business owners, get familiar with their role in relation to the product
- Get multiple roles, and work through the application at all levels
- Compare and review code relating to the application at each point in the reivew
- Find out the roles of the other team members (i.e. who is the data access specialist, who codes the front end, etc).

I would like to flesh this out more for future interviews (I have a quick interview with the lead coding analyst next week as a level set on my coding skills), to show that this is something that could be done remotely.

**What needs to be added to the above approach to show awareness of the difficulties of managing a process and team from a remote location?**

Answer (score 1):

If the main area of concern with the position being remote is the "getting up to speed" aspect then would it be feasible for you to spend some initial time on-site in order to have either meetings with the appropriate people or perhaps shadow them during their work?

In the longer term I think you need to build something into your approach regarding communication, be it scheduling regular Skype conf calls. Perhaps regular visits to the main site? (Frequency of these would probably depend upon need and the distance involved). Consider also that communication is a two-way thing, it may sound obvious but I think it would be worth making explicit mention of how you would go about ensuring you were available for the team to contact *you* as well.